# request for index path for global index 6 when there are only 6 items in the collection view

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

When user tapped on a view I am performing a batch update. I m moving first item of second section to first portion in first section. But app is getting crash with error "request for index path for global index 6 when there are only 6 items in the collection view"

Below is the code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Public

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      view.addSubview(collectionView)
      collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor),
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:   view.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor),
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
      ])

      view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewTapped)))
   }

   // MARK:  Private

    private var sections: [Section] = [
    Section(
      id: "s0",
      items: [
        Item(id: "s0i0"),

      ]),
    Section(
      id: "s1",
      items: [
        Item(id: "s1i0"),
         Item(id: "s1i1"),
          Item(id: "s1i2"),
           Item(id: "s1i3"),
            Item(id: "s1i4"),
      ]),
    ]

    private lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
        flowLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 50)
        flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 10, right: 5)
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView.isPrefetchingEnabled = false
        collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        collectionView.register(Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        collectionView.register(
          Header.self,
          forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader,
          withReuseIdentifier: "Header")
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        return collectionView
    }()

    @objc private func viewTapped() {
      collectionView.performBatchUpdates({

      let section1Item0 = sections[1].items.remove(at: 0)
      sections[0].items.insert(section1Item0, at: 0)

      collectionView.moveSection(1, toSection: 1)

      collectionView.moveItem(
          at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 1),
          to: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0))
      }, completion: { (finished) in
          print("Done: \(finished)")
      })
    }
}

// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

   func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
       return sections.count
   }

   func collectionView(  _ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int)
    -> Int {
       return sections[section].items.count
   }


   func collectionView( _ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
      cell.text = "\(sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.item].id) - {\(indexPath.section), \(indexPath.item)}"
      return cell
   }


   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
       let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView( ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "Header", for: indexPath) as! Header
       header.text = "\(sections[indexPath.section].id) - \(indexPath.section)"
       return header
   }
}
```

Comment: You are moving a section to the same place which looks strange, `collectionView.moveSection(1, toSection: 1)`, but I have no idea if this does any harm and you should point out at what line in your code the crash occurs

Comment: collectionView.moveItem(
        at: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 1),
        to: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0))
    }, completion: { (finished) in
      print("Done: \(finished)")
    })

Comment: Then I would use the debugger to see exactly what happens when you move a section onto itself or just in general to check what the content of `sections` is right before the crash.

Comment: yes that the issue. when move and move from section are same it crashes.

Comment: So problem solved then, maybe you should remove this question.